# How do I write package.xml?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across several tutorials about catkin and especially the [package.xml](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml) tutorial; I wonder how should I write the `package.xml`. Here is a simple example:

### package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>ensenso_n10_description</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Ensenso end effector for Fanuc M10iA</description>
  <maintainer email="my_mail@gmail.com">Name</maintainer>
  <license>All rights reserved</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<!--
  <run_depend>joint_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>robot_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rviz</run_depend>
  <run_depend>xacro</run_depend>
-->
</package>
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ensenso_n10_description)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

catkin_package()

foreach(dir launch meshes urdf)
  install(
    DIRECTORY ${dir}/
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/${dir})
endforeach()
```

I was expecting things not to work with the commented out section, but it turns out it works well without the `run_depend` tags.
I've manually written `package.xml` but I don't understand how I am supposed to fill the `build_depend` and `run_depend` tags.

1. How do I check that my `package.xml` is correctly written? (I only know [catkin_lint](https://github.com/fkie/catkin_lint))
2. In what cases would anything fail if the `package.xml` is wrong?
3. Is there a tool that automatically writes the `package.xml`? (using the `CMakeLists.txt` for example).
   If it's not possible, why?
4. Why is information duplicated between `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202322/how-do-i-write-package.xml?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I was expecting things not to work with the commented out section, but it turns out it works well without the `run_depend` tags. The full package can be viewed [here](https://github.com/VictorLamoine/ensenso_n10_description).

The package manifest is mostly used for resolving dependencies for packages *when they are being installed*, either from source (using `rosdep`), or (after processing by Bloom) by the Debian/Fedora/X package manager. The buidfarm also uses this information.

That things still work on your local machine makes perfect sense: you already have all dependencies installed. Removing the `run_depend`s from your manifest does not change that fact.

<del>(note that for Python this is slightly different, as in that case `run_depends` are also used to setup the Python path in your workspace).</del> (probably not true, see also [REP-122/PYTHONPATH, roslib.load_manifest()](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html#pythonpath-roslib-load-manifest))

> I've manually written `package.xml` but I don't understand how I am supposed to fill the `build_depend` and `run_depend` tags.

Most people (at least initially) use the [catkin_create_pkg](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/catkin/CreatingPackage) command, with appropriate arguments. If, during development, you find that you need to add more dependencies, simply edit the file by hand, as you have done now.

As to whether things are a `run_depend`, `build_depend` or `test_depend` (and sometimes also *why*), the [How to do common tasks](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html) section (from the [catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/index.html)) is probably very helpful (note: the linked version is for Indigo).

> 1 . How do I check that my `package.xml` is correctly written? (I only know [catkin_lint](https://github.com/fkie/catkin_lint))

[REP-127](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html) would be the authorative source for information on whether the manifest is 'correctly written'. The [catkin/package.xml](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml) tutorial you linked would be the more informal version of that.

As to dependencies: `catkin_lint` actually makes sure that the manifest and `CMakeLists.txt` are consistent with each other (it also performs syntax and 'best practice' conformance checks). It cannot know whether a dependency you stated in your manifest or `CMakeLists.txt` is actually needed / correct. It does not parse your C++. You are the only one (at the moment) with that knowledge.

Failing builds would be a sign of missing dependencies in `CMakeLists.txt`.

> 2 . In what cases would anything fail if the package.xml is wrong?

See earlier comments.

> 3 . Is there a tool that automatically writes the `package.xml`? (using the `CMakeLists.txt` for example). If it's not possible, why?

I don't know of a tool that can generate `package.xml` for you, but `catkin_lint` at least does the consistency checks for you. Whether it would be possible to create such a tool: Python packages would be one example of why that is difficult (with only `run_depends`, and an almost empty `CMakeLists.txt`).

> 4 . Why is information duplicated between `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`?

I think others (like @Dirk Thomas, @William) can probably answer this in more detail, but in general I consider `CMakeLists.txt` to be the *build script*, while `package.xml` is where we store mostly other metadata. Some things are duplicated, but (I think) only because it is complicated to deduce generic rules for translating build dependencies into run dependencies (on some platforms, all build deps are suffixed with `-dev`, but that is hardly a general rule. There could even be pkgs for which the runtime libraries are in a package with a completely different name than the development artefacts).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-04**:
"(note that for Python this is slightly different, as in that case run_depends are also used to setup the Python path in your workspace)." I do not believe this is correct, the `PYTHONPATH` should be set independently of the `run_depends`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-05**:
I wasn't entirely sure of it myself, but I have had packages where things don't work if I didn't add dependencies to `run_depends` and rebuilt. Perhaps they were just coincidences.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-05**:
IIUC, you are right @William. I've edited the answer.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-09**:
In response to why stuff is duplicated, I can only answer by saying each place a dependency is used is for a specific reason. And by leaving it out in one place or another you can control how your package uses that dependency. It's hard to guess the intention of the user based on the package.xml.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-09**:
I've explained it a bit before, see: http://answers.ros.org/question/201977/include-header-file-from-another-package-indigo/?answer=201983#post-id-201983

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-09**:
Also, this one sort of explains part of it too: http://answers.ros.org/question/58498/what-is-the-purpose-of-catkin_depends/#58593